# conda installed pip failed to find packages

Tags: installation, pip, conda

[conda_pip_failed.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyJ31.gif)

Conda installed pip seems to fail for nearly every package, but the one in /usr/bin/ works fine, what could be the problem?

The Error message:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> [any_package]

Please see the gif.

Answer (score 0):

well, maybe you can try to install it manually bypassing Pypi like this:

```
pip install git+https://gitlab.com/ase/ase
```

Comment: This may be a solution if I only need to install a single package. What happened is that conda-installed pip failed for nearly every package that can be installed by the system-default pip.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  a deleted answer (maybe he deleted it himself or maybe it was detected as some kind of AI generated answer), I solved this question by following commands:

```bash
conda update conda
conda update pip
pip install [any package]
```

Turns out it was due to the out-of-date `pip` that may lack some necessary parts to work properly, simply updated to the latest version fixed this problem.